# Polars: use left shift operator in an apply expression

Tags: python-polars

I have a python-polars dataframe:

```
┌───────┬─────┐
│ val1  ┆ val2│
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ f32   ┆ i32 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 0.0   ┆ 3   │
│ 1.0   ┆ 3   │
│ 1.0   ┆ 3   │
│ 1.0   ┆ 3   │
│ ...   ┆ ... │
│ 0.667 ┆ 3   │
│ 1.0   ┆ 3   │
│ 0.333 ┆ 3   │
│ 0.333 ┆ 3   │
└───────┴─────┘
```

I'd like to do this operation to replace the two columns above with one column obtained by:

`((val1 * 100) << 16) + val2`

I have a function that can take values from the two columns and do this operation, but it is not expressive and is a python lambda function which makes it quite slow.

```py
df.select(((pl.col("val1") * 100) << 16) + pl.col("val2"))

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'Expr' and 'int'
#
# unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'Expr' and 'int'
```

I can run `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` in place of `<<`, but it does not work with bitwise shift operators.

Is this possible in polars? I saw that there is a [function in polars-rust](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/export/num/traits/trait.CheckedShl.html) that does a left shift, but I don't know how or if that can be used with python.

Comment: I don't think any bitwise operations are exposed as of yet - there are some [open issues on the tracker.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues?q=bitwise) You could use numpy .e.g `df.select(np.left_shift(pl.col("val1") * 100, 16) + pl.col("val2"))`

Comment: In this context, isn't `<< 16` equivalent to dividing by `2^16`. So something like that: `df.select(((pl.col("val1") * 100) / (2 ** 16)) + pl.col("val2"))`

Comment: Almost - it works by multiplying with 2^16. 

`df.select(((pl.col("val1") * 100) * (2 ** 16)) + pl.col("val2"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pyarrow since converting from polars to arrow is free and more importantly because pyarrow does have bit shifting although only for integers.

```
#start with
df=pl.DataFrame({'val1':[0.0,1.0,1.0,0.667,1,0,0.33,0.33], 'val2':[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]})

# make a pa array of the val1 * 100 and cast it to Int
padf=df.with_columns([(pl.col('val1')*100).cast(pl.Int64())]).to_arrow()

# import pyarrow and then use `shift_left`
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc
df=df.with_columns((pl.from_arrow(pc.shift_left(padf['val1'], pa.scalar(16))).alias('shifted'))).with_columns((pl.col('shifted')+pl.col('val2')).alias('result'))
```

I just noticed @jquerious's comment.  That's actually a good approach because `np.left_shift` is a [ufunc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/numpy.html).

It just needs a couple tweaks

```
 df \
    .with_columns(
        np.left_shift((pl.col('val1')*100).cast(pl.Int64()),16).alias('npres'))
```

Comment: np.left_shift was a little faster than the 2^16 approach when I tested on my data.

Comment: as well as the pyarrow method.